# Django + Nginx настройка для двух сетевых интерфейсов

Tags: django, nginx

К серверу подключены два сетевых интерфейса с выходом в интернет (динамика и статика) и развернут сайт на Djаngo. Через динамику осуществляется доступ к сайту по локальной сети, а через статику доступ к сайту по доменному имени. Если подключить только статику, то сайт доступен через интернет, если вставить 2 сетевых интерфейса, то ресурс доступен только в локальной сети. Вот конфиг nginx

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name мой IP;
    return 444;
}
 server {
listen  80;
server_name local_ip_1 local_ip_2  mysite.com;

client_max_body_size 10000m;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /static/ {
    root /home/myAPP;
}
location = /update/ {
    root /home/myAPP;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    
}



location / {
    
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;

    
}
```

Как правильно настроить nginx для двух сетевых интерфейсов?